# How to load a jsp having GWT module into main.jsp which contains header and footer

Tags: jquery, gwt

I would like to call a JSP having GWT module from a `main.jsp` which contains header and footer. These GWT modules should be loaded on the body of `main.jsp`. Based on the link which one clicks from the header.jsp that respective GWT module should be loaded within the body of `main.jsp`:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#clickMe").click(function() {
   // This gwtModule.jsp contains only GWT module.
   $("#name").load("/gwtModule.jsp");
    });
   });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  ${headerAndMenuCache}
   <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>
    <a href="#" id="clickMe">clickMe</a>
    <div id="name">
    </div>      
    <jsp:include page="/footer.jsp" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It's not working?

Comment: Yes, It is not rendering/loading the GWT generated nocache.js file.

Comment: All I want to do is that, I would like to load the GWT generated nocahce.js file when I click on any menuItem  through JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of `jQuery.load()` if your GWT nocache js was not loaded.
2. Make sure that your GWT script is ready to render necessary components into some div. You need to set up this in entry point:

```java
SimplePanel appWidget = new SimplePanel();
activityManager.setDisplay(appWidget);
// I suppose that you want to use your <div id="name">
RootPanel.get("name").add(appWidget);
```

Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Maksym but, No someHow it is not loading the gwt module. You please check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746771/how-to-dynamically-load-a-gwt-generated-nocache-js-file