# How to dynamically load a gwt generated nocache.js file?

Tags: jquery, gwt

I would like to load a GWT generated `foo/foo/nocache.js` file dynamically by using JQuery. SomeHow this `foo/foo/nocache.js` file is not executed by the browser. If I put the script normally by using GWT style withOut using the JQuery, then after the page is loaded it is generating a script(ie..,  jquery.onInjectDone('jquery') ) dynamically. Now if I create this script tag using JQuery or javaScript then it is not generating the dynamically generated script.

Now how can I make sure that `foo/foo/nocache.js` is executed using jQuery?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#clickMe").click(function() {
   // This /foo/foo.nocache.js which is generated by GWT compiler.
       $.getScript("/foo/foo.nocache.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
           console.log(data); //data returned
           console.log(textStatus); //success
           console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
           console.log('Load was performed.');
        });
    });
   });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>
    <a href="#" id="clickMe">clickMe</a>
    <div id="name">
    </div>      
 </body>
</html>
```

Output:

> ReferenceError: foo is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the linker you are using, you could not load the `.nocache.js` script after the document creation has been finished because it loads the appropriate permutation by using `document.write` (see [IFrameTemplate.js#344](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/linker/IFrameTemplate.js#344) and  [XSTemplate.js#279](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/linker/XSTemplate.js#279) ). This makes that all your current content in your page would be overwritten.

Otherwise, If you select `xsiframe` linker, you can load the script, but the algorithm it uses to compute where the permutation is, uses the script tag or the location of your document, so you cannot load it using ajax but inserting a script tags.

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  $('body').append($("<script src=foo/foo.nocache.js />")); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Manolo. xsiframe linker perfectly suited for our requirement. It has worked. I'm soo happy.

Comment: Hello Manolo, I would like to add the histroy for the menuItem using the JQuery. Now I've got some problem. I've already posted. Please check the link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946154/jquery-and-gwt-history-support-get-mixed-up