# How would like to load the GWT module dyanamically basing on the click of respective link?

Tags: jquery, gwt

I would like to load different gwt modules withIn the main div basing on the click of respective menuItem. I would like to use JQuery.  In the below code, I would like to load the `fooGwt module` if we click on the `loadFooModule` and similarly, if I click on `loadJqueryModule` link then `JQuery gwt module` should be loaded.

```
Code:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="menuItem" uri="menuItem" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
          $("#fooModule").empty();
          $("#jQueryModule").empty();
      $("#main").remove();
          alert($(this).text());
          if ($(this).text() == "loadJqueryModule") {
                  // Jquery gwt module.
              $('head').append($("<script id='main' src='/jquery/jquery.nocache.js' />")); 
          } else {
                   // Foo GWt module.
              $('head').append($("<script id='main' src='/foo/foo.nocache.js' />")); 
          }
    });
  });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>
    <a href="#" id="clickMe">loadFooModule</a>
    <a href="#" id="clickMe5">loadJqueryModule</a>
    <div id="fooModule">
    </div>      
    <div id="jQueryModule">
    </div>      
 </body>
</html>
```

O/p:
In this it is loading one module which is Foo. The other module was not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a module dynamically you have to be aware of two things:

1. Compile your modules using the `xsiframe` linker
2. Insert it using the `<script>` tag.

I did answer the a similar question some days ago: [How to dynamically load a gwt generated nocache.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746771/how-to-dynamically-load-a-gwt-generated-nocache-js-file/16758117) . Take a look to it to know more about these constrains.

Your js code to dynamically insert the `script` seems ok, so check that both modules were compiled using the `xsiframe` linker.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach feels backwords. You want GWT to control the webpage and then you can use code splitting https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting to control when each module loads.

Comment: Yes Kenoyer, I'm using codeSplitting withIn the GWT module. But I've 10 GWT modules and each module itSelf will do codeSplitting. Now my problem is that, I don't want to do any HTTP request onClick of any menuItem. There should be only one JSP which will add the scripts dynamically because I don't want to load all the header and footer jsps once again and I would like to cut my intial HTTP request which will just do the dispatch.