# JQuery and GWT History support get mixed up

Tags: jquery, gwt

I'm dynamically appending GWT scripts using JQuery and then tracking the history using JQuery history.

**Problem**: My GWT modules generate the `History` tokens because all of my GWT modules are MVP modules. And  `onClick()`s of `MenuItem`s is dynamically loading the GWT module, along withThis I'm adding the history for the `MenuItems` using JQuery. But my GWT modules also use `History`. Now the problem is that If I repetitively click on the `MenuItem` which loads `GWT MVP modules` , someHow my browser is getting strucked.

**code:**

```
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/newclickmenu/jquery.history.js"></script>

                 // Contains code which creates menuItems using JSTL. In this menuItem there will be menuItem and *subMenuItem(onclick of menuItem there will be a slideDown which would show subMenuItem


                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(window).load(function() {
                            $('body').on('click', '#subMenuItem', function(event) {
                                // onClick of subMenuItem(which is anchor) then it add the History and will invoke the GWT mvp module.
                                // After doing the push then below `$.history.on('load change push', function(event, url, type) {` line is called.
                                $.history.push($(this).attr("href"));
                                event.preventDefault();
                            });
                            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
                            $.history.on('load change push', function(event, url, type) {
                                if (event.type == "load") {
                                    if (url.split("!").length < 2) {
                                        window.location = url;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // This code will add the GWT module dynamically.
                                    if (typeof url !== undefined && url !== null && url !== "") {
                                        // Remove the old GWT script and append the new script
                                        var previousModule = $(".mainModule");
                                        if (previousModule.parent().length !== 0) {
                                            $(previousModule).remove();
                                        }
                                        var expectedUrl = "<script class='mainModule' src='/Masters/Masters.cache.js'/>";
                                        $('head').append($(expectedUrl));
                                    }
                                }
                        )};
                            }).listen('hash');
                    </script>
```

Comment: I suggest you should add some code of yours.

Comment: I've added the code please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable the GWT´s History?

Reading the official documentation  [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory#example)

```
To use GWT History support, you must first embed an iframe into your host HTML page.
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" 
          style="width:0;height:0;border:0" />
```

Try to delete it, compile your modules again.

Anyway only for curiosity, why are you using with jQuery injection of GWT´s scripts? I think is much better do in the reverse way.

You can create an Activity and Places desing, control your History in a really simple way, and use the GWT´s script injector for your jQuery scripts.

```
    final JavaScriptObject idScript = $(window).prop("IDSCRIPT");
    if (idScript == null){
       ScriptInjector.fromUrl("js/jq/myJqueryScript.js").setCallback(
        new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
          public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
              AppConf.C("Trying to inject js/fb/myJqueryScript. Fail.");
          }
          public void onSuccess(Void result) {
              executeMyStuff(...);
          }
        }).inject();
    } else {
        executeMyStuff(...);
    }
```

Comment: Well the scenario has changed completely. Why are you injecting the GWT module each time? 
Well, the idea is load the GWT module once, and inside it you have the control of your widgets and stuff for doing things whatever you want, whenever you want. 

Also what do you mean by strucked? Any consolo error? Any picture? Can you give us more details?

Comment: Yes, apanizo. I'm trying to make my modules render faster.onClick of menuItem it is just doing dispatch. So, I though to cut that Http request. I've almost cut the Http request. Moreover I'm using the cached Js so, the rendering time would be even faster and than the normal one.
Problem wise: If it is google chrome, it has asked me to kill and reload the page.
I'm thinking that, the JQuery history and my gwt module history change event are invoking at a time.

Comment: Wait for more answers because I am still confused. Reading your post before the modification I thought you were injecting in some way the GWT ´s History. But if you inject only the js and you don´t have in any place the html code that I posted before, there is no GWT´s History dealing in your app. I am not sure if youu have understood my second answer. You are doing  $('head').append($(expectedUrl)); why all the times (is not the idea of GWT)? Anyway before doing the append try to **delete** the previous GWT module (if is the 2+ time).

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is very complex, I dont know the reason you need this in your app, but anyway:

1- When you add a gwt-module you cannot unload it. So although you remove the script tag, the code is loaded in memory, and all events gwt has added continue in exectution.

2- If your gwt-module changes the history token your jquery code listening for history events, will be called each time.

3- This setup could work for the first gwt module loaded, but the second module would interfere with the first one since both are adding certain event handlers to the same thing. So each mvp gwt-module loaded is listening for history events, mouse events, etc, and you will get an uncertain behavior.

Maybe if you explain a bit more about your app architecture and requirements, we could figure out a most suitable setup.

Comment: Please check the link that explains the simplified architecture for discussion purpose. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983265/how-to-load-gwt-modules-using-the-jquery

Comment: The below link shows you my current project architecture and the problem which my users are facing. So, please help me what should I do inOrder to achieve my goal?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983265/how-to-load-gwt-modules-using-the-jquery
I've made a possible progress but due to the problem which you have mentioned ie.., **the code is loaded in memory** I've got struck in the middle. I'm unable to make a progress. Please help me out for the best suitable setup.