# How to Load GWT modules using the JQuery?

Tags: jquery, gwt

Our application has many large GWT modules developed over time.
Architecture is Servlets/JSP and GWT.

I am simplifying here. 
`Link1.jsp`  contains `Link1 GWT module` 
`Link2.jsp` contains `Link2 Gwt module` 
`Link3.jsp`  contains `Link3 GWT module`.

**All the above 3 jsps are same, ie, include same header and footer. 
Only body is changing based on the GWT module.**

Now, we are trying to improve the performance while the user is clicking the above links.
When the user is clicking `Link1.jsp`, the request is sent to server and the response
is coming back in **500-700ms**.(We are in India and hence the **latency issues**)
The user is complaining about the slowness of the application for every link click.

Hence, we are trying the following:
Since all the jsps are exactly same and only the body is changing, we decided not 
to make `default href request` for the above links and we are trying to load the different 
GWT modules based on the click link using JQuery.

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, you mentioned this happening for every link click, so the first step would be to look into proper caching headers, I'd say! The browser doesn't have to re-download all the module files for each request, just for the first one.

Comment: You are correct WouterH. I'm doing the same thing, but I've got some problem. Please check the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946154/jquery-and-gwt-history-support-get-mixed-up

Answer (score 1):

I did [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746771/how-to-dynamically-load-a-gwt-generated-nocache-js-file/16758117#comment24523132_16758117) this question a while ago. Basically, compile your modules using the `xsiframe` linker and load your modules using dinamically generated `<script>` tags:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  $('body').append($("<script src=foo/foo.nocache.js />")); 
}
```

## Update:

Trying to figure out why you need this architecture, IMO maybe you are trying a wrong solution.

If all of your app is based in GWT modules, why to introduce external javascript libraries?

GWT has its own mechanism to face the problem of speeding up the initial loading. I think you should create a super-gwt-module which includes all sub-modules you have in your application.

- The super module would be the unique `EntryPoint` in your app, and the responsible to handle the links in your jsp. Probably I would use [gwtquery](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting) for that module, but it is up to you.
- Other modules should be loaded using [code-splitting](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting), so they are not `EntryPoint` but `RunAsyncCallback`.

The advantages of this solution are a lot. And you will have an application which loads really fast:

- You dont load external libraries like jquery: about 100KB compressed.
- The first fragment to load would be super-small, probabely 30-50 KB if you use gquery (much less than jquery itself)
- Many of the code shared by the modules (gwt-core, jre, etc), could go to the first fragment and would be shared by all the modules, decreasing the final downloaded size of each module.
- It is an out-of-the-box solution, gwt compiler makes a good job splitting the code and adding everything to load it asynchronously when demanded.
- Configuring correctly your webserver, clients would cache the app for ever.
- Java ecosystem facilitates modular apps.

Another options in GWT-2.5.1 to decrease js size are:

- Remove stack code: `<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="strip"/>`
- Pre-compress your js files: `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.precompress.Precompress"/>`
- Use the [closure](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript) compiler: `-XenableClosureCompiler`
- Remove class metadata: `-XdisableClassMetadata`
- Disable castings: `-XdisableCastChecking`
- Optimize code-splitting: `-XfragmentCount 20`

Comment: I've done the same thing Manolo. But I ran into problems because of the JQuery history. What could be the possible solution for that problem which I've faced:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946154/jquery-and-gwt-history-support-get-mixed-up